# java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.addtoUserFriendList) must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello i am getting such an error i couldn't find the solution for the error ;

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.chatapp/com.example.chatapp.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.addtoUserFriendList)
> must not be null

My Code is:

```
private lateinit var userRecyclerView: RecyclerView

private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<User>
    
private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
  
 private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    
private lateinit var addFriend: Button
  
  private lateinit var mDbRef: DatabaseReference
   
 var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle? = null
   
 private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()


        userList = ArrayList()
        adapter = UserAdapter(this, userList)

        userRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userRecyclerview)

        userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        userRecyclerView.adapter = adapter


            mDbRef.child("user").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    userList.clear()
                    for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val user = postSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                        if (mAuth.currentUser?.uid != user?.uid) {
                            userList.add(user!!)
                        }
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

                }

            })

        addFriend = findViewById(R.id.addtoUserFriendList)

        addFriend.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            var friend = Friend(name = "Merhaba", "merhaba@gmail.com")
            saveFriend(friend)
        }
    }
`
```

Code of layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="3dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addtoUserFriendList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Arkadaş Olarak Ekle"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="244dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Hasan"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried but i couldn't solve it

Comment: Could you send your XML file with layout?

Comment: [link](http://notepad.link/share/yyNcYviLerkFBWtwEskH) -< Here

Comment: Are you sure what you posted is `activity_main.xml`? It doesn't have your `userRecyclerView`, and your code isn't crashing when it attempts to find that. Also you should be doing `setContentView(binding.root)`, or you'll be displaying a different set of views than the ones you're setting up, and nothing will work. Also you need to add constraints to those views in the XML, those `absolute_x` etc values only work in the layout editor, for testing

Comment: Since you are using a binding, you need to call `setContentView(binding.root)`, not the version you have. You also don't need any `findViewById` calls - any view you have available will be in the binding class already. If it's not in the binding class, `findViewById` won't find it either and will return null. For example, you can just use `binding.addtoUserFriendList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `addFriend` button is in another XML file, because there is no such view in the file you attached.

You must declare addFriend button in the `activity_main` file in order to use it in your code inside `Activity`.

Comment: I am using recyclerview in activity main. I am listing user layout with recyclerview, inside user layout there is addtoUserFriendList button

Comment: Are you sure you attached the right XML file (activity_main) then?

Comment: Thank you it's  worked without recyclerview. But i think i fixed it with use adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a not null variable `private lateinit var addFriend: Button` and did pass it a null value. It's the reason that you're getting null pointer exception. For fix make variable nullable like `private lateinit var addFriend: Button?` or just pass a not null value to it.

Comment: I tried it but lateinit var cannot be used with Nullable.